# Framework not found

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I developed the framework and when I run the project it shows the error message "Framework" not found.[image]
I don't know where is the issue, I cannot add the framework in FrameWorks folder.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Very hard to provide any help based on single screenshot. Please create a reproducible problem description

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer this question that can help someone else.
When you add .framework in your target, from build phase menu, you need to add "New copy file phases" and make destination as a Framework then from plus button add your framework.